# "Bring All to Front" is missing in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3

I am using QGIS 3.4 and 3.10 and a plugin's window ends up hiding behind the canvas. In QGIS 2.10 I had the option `"Bring All to Front"` to bring all windows to front.

Is there an alternative for it in QGIS 3?

This is on Mac OSX High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: What happens if you type `iface.mainWindow().findChild( QAction, 'mActionWindowAllToFront' ).trigger()` in the Python Console?

Comment: Thanks, Joseph! I tried it but got this error msg: "raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/QGIS3.4.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'trigger'"